# create product attribute media in soap v1 error 102

Tags: api, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to insert an image within the product register in my store using webservice xml soap V1 with the SoapUI program.
Reference: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttributeMedia/catalog_product_attribute_media.create.html
My request:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento" xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">   
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:call>
         <sessionId>fdda3f97e9f6d472d4d4d4d5807f54957d73</sessionId>
         <resourcePath>catalog_product_attribute_media.create</resourcePath>
         <args SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns2:Map[2]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:array">
         <product xsi:type="xsd:string">38</product>
         <storeView xsi:type="xsd:int">1</storeView>
         <store_id xsi:type="xsd:int">1</store_id>
         <identifierType xsi:type="xsd:string">product</identifierType>
         <!-- starts first array -->
          <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
            <item>
              <key xsi:type="xsd:string">content</key> 
              <value xsi:type="xsd:string">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</value>
            </item>
            <item>   
              <key xsi:type="xsd:string">mime</key> 
              <value xsi:type="xsd:string">image/jpeg</value>
            </item>      
            <item>   
              <key xsi:type="xsd:string">name</key> 
              <value xsi:type="xsd:string">imagemteste</value>
            </item>   
          </item> <!-- ends first array -->
          <!-- starts second array -->
            <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
              <item>   
              <key xsi:type="xsd:string">label</key> 
              <value xsi:type="xsd:string">label01</value>
              </item>      
              <item>   
              <key xsi:type="xsd:string">position</key> 
              <value xsi:type="xsd:string">1</value>
              </item> 
              <item>   
              <key xsi:type="xsd:string">types</key> 
              <value xsi:type="xsd:ArrayOfString">thumbnail</value>
              </item>     
              <item>   
              <key xsi:type="xsd:string">exclude</key> 
              <value xsi:type="xsd:string">0</value>
              </item>   
              <!--<item>   
              <key xsi:type="xsd:string">remove</key> 
              <value xsi:type="xsd:string">0</value>
              </item>-->                              
            </item> <!-- end second array -->
         <!--<storeView xsi:type="xsd:string">default</storeView> -->
       </args>
      </ns1:call>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

My response (with error):

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>102</faultcode>
         <faultstring>A imagem não está especificada.</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How solves this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is "The image is not specified"
Your "file" key is missing in request check example. "content" and "mime" should be in key "file"

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

$productId = 2;
$file = array(
    'content' => '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',
    'mime' => 'image/jpeg'
);

$result = $proxy->call(
    $session,
    'catalog_product_attribute_media.create',
    array(
        $productId,
        array('file'=>$file, 'label'=>'Label', 'position'=>'100', 'types'=>array('thumbnail'), 'exclude'=>0)
    )
);
```

**UPDATE**
For XML Request try as below

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento" xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:call>
            <sessionId xsi:type="xsd:string">b219d4ec27c5c0c399ac0335ec2677cc</sessionId>
            <resourcePath xsi:type="xsd:string">catalog_product_attribute_media.create</resourcePath>
            <args SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:ur-type[2]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
                <item xsi:type="xsd:int">38</item>
                <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                    <item>
                        <key xsi:type="xsd:string">file</key>
                        <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                            <item>
                                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">content</key>
                                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">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</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">mime</key>
                                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">image/jpeg</value>
                            </item>
                        </value>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <key xsi:type="xsd:string">label</key>
                        <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Label</value>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <key xsi:type="xsd:string">position</key>
                        <value xsi:type="xsd:string">100</value>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <key xsi:type="xsd:string">types</key>
                        <value SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
                            <item xsi:type="xsd:string">thumbnail</item>
                        </value>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <key xsi:type="xsd:string">exclude</key>
                        <value xsi:type="xsd:int">0</value>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </args>
        </ns1:call>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: thanks for comment, but how can i do this in xml?

Comment: @MatheusSilvaItep updated my answer

Comment: thanks man (your xml is correctly), now its works :-), i will see whats different in my code , thanks again

Comment: @MatheusSilvaItep you can up vote  as well :)